# Can Spark RDD in Scala be var instead of val?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm quite new to Spark/Scala. Can Spark RDD in Scala be var instead of val? I'm try to write a for loop to update RDD in each iteration. If I define it to be val then it would be immutable so I'm just wondering whether I use var RDD instead.

Comment: Perhaps show us what you're trying to do, with a code example

Answer (score 4):

`var` doesn't affect mutability of the assigned object. The only difference is that you can replace the object assigned to a `var`, but you cannot do the same with `val`. You can assign `RDD` to `var` but it still won't be mutable (although can be overwritten). There are more elegant ways of handling things like this though.

Answer (score 1):

Q - Can Spark RDD in Scala be var instead of val?

Ans - Yes, it can be. Spark wont throw error by assigning either of these two keywords, but it is always recommended to use val (because val fields are immutable and spark RDD too is immutable).

I tried this PFB screen shot of small code snippet

[image]

The difference between val and var is that val makes a variable immutable — like final in Java — and var makes a variable mutable like normal variable in any programming language.
Because val fields can’t change, that is what we need while working with spark rdd i.e. immutable data type.